# Can I get the custom filed of customer in sales order screen?

Tags: acumatica

I had created a custom field "Inner Branch ID" on customer screen.
My question is how to get the value of it in sales order BLC? Use PXSelect method? It really confused me...

[image: Custom filed]

[image: On sales order screent]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just show custom field added to the Customer you can do as it is shown on the screenshot below
[image]

If you want to get the value of the Custom Field in the code under some event or action you can do the following:

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects.SO;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using System;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class SOOrderEntryExt: PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
    {
        public virtual void Customer_RowSelecting(PXCache sender,PXRowSelectingEventArgs eventArgs,PXRowSelecting baseMethod)
        {
            baseMethod?.Invoke(sender, eventArgs);
            if(eventArgs.Row!=null)
            {
                Customer currentCustomer = (Customer)eventArgs.Row;
                BAccountExt currentCustomerExtension = PXCache<BAccount>.GetExtension<BAccountExt>(currentCustomer);
                var value = currentCustomerExtension.UsrCustomerNote;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Customer` is inherited from `BAccount` class so there will not be any issue under the following line:

```
BAccountExt currentCustomerExtension = PXCache<BAccount>.GetExtension<BAccountExt>(currentCustomer);
```

After this line you have the value of the custom field and can do with it what you need:

```
var value = currentCustomerExtension.UsrCustomerNote;
```

Comment: First thx for your reply. But I'm a little confused. If I wanna get the customer of the current SO(on screen), and then get the custom field of the customer. Can your code works for that?

Comment: @JackZeng yes,this code is working for the current customer of the Sales Order

Comment: If I dont wanna do it in Customer_RowSelecting event, instead of doing it in Action? Is the code the same? Do I need change these code "Customer currentCustomer = (Customer)eventArgs.Row;" ?

Comment: @JackZeng eventArgs.Row is the current Customer's row boxed as Object. That is why there is casting to Customer type. In case of action instead of using `eventArgs.Row` you can try to get `this.Base.customer.Current` and get it's extension